# COUNT the number of times a DAX measure is > X

Tags: powerbi, dax

New to DAX.
I have a rather (from my point of view) complicated tables relationship model :
[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5I3X.png)
It's a knowledge database in my company.

There are many "compétences" for each employee in table DONNEES. These "compétences" are categorized in the LMC table which is a bridge table between COMP & METIERS  defining the "compétences" needed for a "métier".
One "competence" can be in multiple "métiers"
In table "DONNEES" I have all employees, plus standards profils for each "métier". This table defines the level (1 to 5) for each "competences".

My matrix in Power Bi works like a charm. I can sum all "competences level" for each métiers.
I've added a measure, which normalizes this sum over the sum gotten for each standard profil (this sum is "hard coded" in METIERS, not calulated)

```
Grade = CALCULATE(SUM(DONNEES[Niveau]); LMC)/CALCULATE(SUM(METIERS[Niveau_type]);LMC)*5
```

And it works (even if the "total" columnn isn't correct)

//EDIT//

With the following modifications, it works :

```
Grade = CALCULATE(SUM(DONNEES[Niveau]); LMC,DONNEES,METIERS)/CALCULATE(SUM(METIERS[Niveau_type]);LMC,DONNEES,METIERS)*5
```

(I've added all tables from my many to many relationship)

The grand total column is now ok.

//EDIT//

Now, I want to compute a the number of employee that fulffil a specific grade for each métier.
I've thought to create a binary measure that checks that :

```
gradefulfilled= IF(DONNEES[Grade]>4,5;1;0)
```

An then use the total row to have the number of employees in the company able to do that "métier"

It doesn't work. The total sticks to zero, even if the gradefulfilled binary is correct for everyone.

//EDIT//

The total does'nt stick to zero, it can be 1 if there's one employee OK, but sticks to 1 if more than one employee.

//EDIT//

You can propose either a totally different way to compute what I want (number of employees able to do a "métier" or explain to me where I made a mistake in my computations.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray !
My bad. Problem seems solved.

The problem seems related to the way grand total is calculated in pivot table (the sum of the measure calulated for each line, not on the sum of each measure in the matrix)

So I've used a sumx to get a proper sum :

```
Nbgradefulfilled = sumX(NOMS;DONNEES[gradefulfilled])
```